# Call a method in an aspx page

Tags: asp.net, methods

Can I call a method which is in an asp.net web page (in aspx.cs page) without checking it in the pageload?

for example '../test2.aspx/TestMethod

In [this link](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) I have noticed that we can give   url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName", in jquery ajax method. I have tried it and never works for me.

Comment: is your method static ?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: Can I call a method which is in an asp.net web page (in aspx.cs page) without checking it in the pageload?

for example can I give like '../test2.aspx/TestMethod' in the browser?

Answer (score 4):

Page Methods is a new mechanism in ASP.Net application where the server code cab be bound to Asp.Net pages

To enable Page methods we need to drag a ScriptManager control to the page and mark
the EnablePageMethods to “True”.

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"   
         EnablePageMethods="True">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Go the Code behind file of the page and add a static method

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string HelloWorld(string name)
    {
       return string.Format("Hi {0}",name);
    }
```

In javascript function we can use PageMethods object to call the WebMethod of the page.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function GreetingsFromServer() {
       var name = 'Jalpesh';
       PageMethods.HelloWorld(name,OnSuccess, OnError);
       return false;
   }
   function OnSuccess(response) {
       alert(response);
   }
   function OnError(error) {
       alert(error);
   }
   </script>
```

Comment: This is working fine in case of a .net page (Call to same .net page server side method). But I need something different..

Comment: I have two .net web pages say test1.aspx and test2.aspx. From test1.aspx I have to call a method in test2.aspx.cs (by using ajax or something). Can I do this?

Comment: Darshan, where I can specify the url? In GreetingsFromServer()? Please explain me.

Answer (score 2):

you can use ajax call for another page webmethod

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
  $("#Result").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
         data: "{}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(msg) {
         // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
         $("#Result").text(msg.d);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to do like this url: "Default.aspx/GetDate"??? Do I need to add any extra script or asp:ScriptManager to achieve this one? Please explain me.

Comment: no you dnt required script manager to run this, only you required is jquery reference to be add...

Comment: Sorry its not worked for me.. Are you sure we can call method by giving url: "Default.aspx/GetDate" in asp.net? When I tried like this Im redirecting into the error part in ajax..

Comment: In http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/ I have noticed something like this.. But for that we need to include a script.